# Create both child and parent object on a single Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce

I have a relationship like this:

Class Student  Lookup on Student

Contact Student Master-Detail on Student

I want to create a visualforce page to create new Class and on the same page add Student to the class.

I created a controller extension of Class's controller.

I am now stuck on adding student for the class.

I have several requirements here:

1.I want to add a lookup field to add student to the class.
(However, I'm on the parent object and how can I add this lookup field?)

2.I want to be able to create new student on the page.
Is there a way to do this?

3.I want to be able to add students by importing a file containing student ids.
Is there a way to do this?

Appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not able to add students as you are using a master detail relationship on student with contact. So for adding a student u should also add the contact id in the master detail relationship of contact.

Example.

```
     Class__C cl = new Class__c();   
     Student__C std = new Student__c();  
     Contact con = new Contact();

       //Add all the class information then insert the class

        insert cl;

       //Add all the information of contact and create a new contact 

         insert con;

        //Add all the information of Student and then....

         std.contact = con.id;
         std.class__c = cl.id;

         insert std;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's worth spending some time with *[Visualforce in Practice](http://www.developerforce.com/guides/Visualforce_in_Practice.pdf)*. The book has a whole section on creating "wizards" in Visualforce.

The gist of the situation is that you're going to want to pass a few page references around to step your user through the process of creating a class then adding students.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Checkout this blog post for a solution on parent and child object creation:

https://salesforcemann.wordpress.com/2016/11/11/pet-project-create-parent-and-child-records-from-visualforce-page-for-any-salesforce-object/

I think this will help your case.